# Configure a SQS trigger for lambda function on serverless

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I would like to add a trigger on my lambda function using serverless.yml instead of configure it manually.

I’m trying to recover QueueArn using Fn::Get because it’s not a good practice paste the entire string.

Here is what I’m trying:

```
resources:
  Resources:        
    WaitingSQS:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue   
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:provider.environment.MY_QUEUE_SQS}


consumerCallbackQueue:
  handler: src/consumer_callback_queue.handler
  description: Consume SQS callback queue
    events:
      - sqs: { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["WaitingSQS", "Arn"]}
```

This is not working. My lambda function is deployed without any errors but the trigger is not added. If I replace sqs attribute value with the string ‘arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXX:waiting-dev‘, it works like a charm.

How can I change my code to make it work?

Comment: is WaitingSQS defined in your serverless.yml as well ?

Comment: Yes. It's defined and created without any errors.

Comment: I've updated the code with WaitingSQS in serverless.yml

Comment: thats weird. fngetatt supports sqs arn as the documentation says. You could also try directly referencing it like `- sqs: Ref: WaitingSQS `.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is probably late but I had a similar issue. Check in the console if the SQS trigger is enabled, in some cases it can get automatically disabled, that is what happened to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).